# Struct parent node refers to itself (infinite loop)

Tags: c++, struct, dijkstra

I'm implementing a Dijkstra's algorithm. The code I've written works in terms of finding the shortest path. However, the problem is when I try to save the path.

Just a heads up: I'm using Stanford's library , so some things might be different (e.g. Set has contains method) but functionality is mostly identical to standard libraries.

```
Vector<Loc> shortestPath(Loc start, Loc end, Grid<double>& world, 
                         double costFn(Loc from, Loc to, Grid<double>& world)) {
    
Vector<Loc> vec;
Map<Loc, double> distanceMap;

TrailblazerPQueue<Loc> queue; // priority queue with decrease key method
Set<Loc> greenNodes;
Set<Loc> yellowNodes;

colorCell(world, start, YELLOW);
queue.enqueue(start, 0);
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Loc currNode = queue.dequeueMin(); // here is the problem
    colorCell(world, currNode, GREEN);
    greenNodes.add(currNode);
    if (currNode == end) {
        break;
    }
    Vector<Loc> neighbourNodes = getNeighbourNodes(currNode, world);
    foreach (Loc node in neighbourNodes) {
        if (greenNodes.contains(node)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!yellowNodes.contains(node)) {
            colorCell(world, node, YELLOW);
            yellowNodes.add(node);
            double distance = distanceMap.get(currNode) + costFn(currNode, node, world);
            distanceMap.put(node, distance);
            node.parent = &currNode; // here is the problem
            queue.enqueue(node, distance);
        } else {
            double distance = distanceMap.get(node);
            double currDistance = distanceMap.get(currNode) + costFn(currNode, node, world);
            if (distance > currDistance) {
                distanceMap.put(node, currDistance);
                node.parent = &currNode;
                queue.decreaseKey(node, distance);
            }
        }
    }
}

return vec;
```

}

Here Grid is just a 2D array and costFn just calculates the cost from one location to the next. The way I try to save the path is assign the location of the previous node to current one. Here's the problem: when I traverse the neighbouring nodes of currNode and set the parent of each one as the &currNode, after setting currNode to the new element from the queue, it now refers to other node, so the node's parent now refers to itself, infinitely.

I've tried many different ways of overcoming this problem, creating new nodes in heap and other stuff, but they didn't really work. I've also tried to create other struct and use that to save locations, but I feel like there should be a fairly simple way to resolve this issue.

I hope my explanation isn't too confusing, I've added markers as comments to which lines cause the problem. Also, I say "node", but the struct is called Loc:

```
struct Loc {
    int row;
    int col;
    Loc* parent;
};
```

Comment: What is "Stanford's library"? (And `foreach (Loc node in neighbourNodes)` does not look like C++.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You can see Stanford's C++ libraries here: https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/cppdoc/ . 

However, the libraries and other functionality don't really play a role in this bug, everything else works other than saving the path (which is just 2 lines).

Comment: Never store a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use. They become invalid as soon as the object you got the address of is destroyed. You need to find some other way to identify nodes.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin Yes, the code works perfectly fine, but I'm just unable to save the path correctly.